# R markdown: inline code inside asis chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I might be getting greedy with markdown features but: is there a way to add inline code to an asis chunk?

````
```{r}
x <- 5
```

```{asis}
The square is `r x^2` # should show up as 'The square is 25'
```
````

Comment: What happens when you render that?

Comment: It says "the square is r x^2"

Comment: What do you want it to say?

Comment: The square is 25

Comment: No, you can't do that.  An `asis` chunk just shows you what you typed.  What you have in your example looks like plain text, so the R code would be processed outside of a chunk.  If you want the styling to make it look like a code chunk I think you'll need to wrap it in some HTML tags and set up CSS to format it.